# Pass-through query with no value for optional parameter of T-SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures

I have an Access form to edit records in a SQL Server 2008 R2 table.

There are 3 fields in the form which could be updated, but it may be that one or all 3 fields still are empty (Null), so the update is to set values the first time.

If the fields are `NULL` at the time it want to run the stored procedure and I add values for the first time the stored procedure fails with missing parameters.

The stored procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAlarmprotokollaendern] 
    @FibuNr nvarchar(10)=Null,
    @FibuNr_alt nvarchar(10),
    @Preis decimal(5,2),
    @Preis_alt decimal(5,2)=null,
    @Alarmnummer int,
    @Kennung nvarchar(10),
    @Verrechnungsintervall int=null,
    @Verrechnungsintervall_alt int=null,
    @UserID int=null,
    @Objektname nvarchar(50)=null,
    @Objektstrasse nvarchar(60)=null,
    @ObjektPLZ nvarchar(6)=null,
    @Objektort nvarchar(50)=null,
    @Kostenstelle int, 
    @Objektnummer int

    UPDATE tblAlarmprotokolle 
    SET Fibunr = coalesce(@Fibunr, @Fibunr_alt), 
        Preis = coalesce(@Preis, @Preis_alt), 
        Verrechnungsintervall = coalesce(@Verrechnungsintervall, @Verrechnungsintervall_alt)
    WHERE 
        (Alarmnummer >= @Alarmnummer AND Kennung = @Kennung) 
        OR (abgerechnet = 0 AND Kennung = @Kennung)
```

I use coalesce to check any new value for the field and the set the old field. But if the old field is NULL then it fails.

How can I make this work?

Thanks
Michael

Comment: @lad2025: you're **wrong** - `COALESCE` has been supported by SQL Server since version **2005** - that's definitely **not** something new in 2012 ....

Comment: I think ISNULL is not the solution as is send this string to the Server:
    EXEC dbo.spAlarmprotokollaendern '11150', '',  56.7, , 32627471, 'DL1100205', 3, , 1, 'Streifenberichte Region Ost', '', '', '', 12190, 593

In this example the 4th and 8th Parameter is Null, coming from Access.

IN Access I built the string in VBA with NZ-Function, if any value is Null. If a fieldtype in Server is varchar I can send '' String, but if the field is int I cannot use 0 because 0 is a value and i cannot send NULL, because then the parameter is missing.

So I Need a replacement for NULL.

Comment: just use nz(arg, "Null"). can you post how you concatenate the sql string in Access?  maybe that can help us

Comment: 2 of your "alt" values are set to null, and one (FibuNr) isn't.  If FibuNr comes in as an empty string, neither FibuNr nor FibuNr_alt will be "Null".

Comment: Sorry, for late reply:
@krish KM: strsql = "EXEC dbo.spAlarmprotokollaendern '" & Nz(Me.FibuNr, """Null""") & "', '"
Leads to an error in SQL-Server Error converting data type varchar to int.:

Nz(Me.Fibunr, "Null") leads to an error in Access

Comment: try this : StrSql = "EXEC dbo.spAlarmprotokollaendern " & IIf(Nz(Me.fibuNr.Value, 0) <= 0, "Null", "'" & Me.fibuNr.Value & "'") 

if you want to send the number as string use '' other wiese  you can eliminate that too..

Answer (score 1):

The placeholder for an optional parameter value of a T-SQL stored procedure is the `DEFAULT` keyword. So, if your Access code is generating the following pass-through query call which is failing

```sql
EXEC dbo.spAlarmprotokollaendern '11150', '', 56.7, , 32627471 ...
```

then have it insert the `DEFAULT` keyword if the corresponding Access value is null:

```sql
EXEC dbo.spAlarmprotokollaendern '11150', '', 56.7, DEFAULT, 32627471 ...
```

Note that your EXEC statement must include the bare keyword `DEFAULT`, not the string value `'DEFAULT'`, for example

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub SO32779923()
    Dim myFibunr, myFibunr_alt, myPreis, myPreis_alt, _
            myAlarmnummer, myKennung, _
            myVerrechnungsintervall, myVerrechnungsintervall_alt, _
            myUserID, myObjektname, myObjektstrasse, myObjektPLZ, _
            myObjektort, myKostenstelle, myObjektnummer
    myFibunr = "11150"
    myFibunr_alt = ""
    myPreis = 56.7
    myPreis_alt = Null
    myAlarmnummer = 32627471
    myKennung = "update_me"
    myVerrechnungsintervall = 4
    myVerrechnungsintervall_alt = Null
    myUserID = 0
    myObjektname = "x"
    myObjektstrasse = "x"
    myObjektPLZ = "x"
    myObjektort = "x"
    myKostenstelle = 0
    myObjektnummer = 0

    Dim spCall As String
    spCall = "EXEC dbo.spAlarmprotokollaendern " & _
            prepForSp(myFibunr) & ", " & _
            prepForSp(myFibunr_alt) & ", " & _
            prepForSp(myPreis) & ", " & _
            prepForSp(myPreis_alt) & ", " & _
            prepForSp(myAlarmnummer) & ", " & _
            prepForSp(myKennung) & ", " & _
            prepForSp(myVerrechnungsintervall) & ", " & _
            prepForSp(myVerrechnungsintervall_alt) & ", " & _
            prepForSp(myUserID) & ", " & _
            prepForSp(myObjektname) & ", " & _
            prepForSp(myObjektstrasse) & ", " & _
            prepForSp(myObjektPLZ) & ", " & _
            prepForSp(myObjektort) & ", " & _
            prepForSp(myKostenstelle) & ", " & _
            prepForSp(myObjektnummer)

    Debug.Print spCall

    Dim cdb As DAO.Database
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("")
    qdf.Connect = "ODBC;DSN=myDb"
    qdf.sql = spCall
    qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
    qdf.Execute
    Set qdf = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function prepForSp(thing As Variant) As String
    If IsNull(thing) Then
        prepForSp = "DEFAULT"
    Else
        Select Case VarType(thing)
            Case vbString:
                prepForSp = "'" & Replace(thing, "'", "''") & "'"
            Case vbDate:
                prepForSp = "'" & Format(thing, "yyyy-mm-dd Hh:Nn:Ss") & "'"
            Case Else
                prepForSp = CStr(thing)
        End Select
    End If
End Function
```

The `Debug.Print` statement displays

```sql
EXEC dbo.spAlarmprotokollaendern '11150', '', 56.7, DEFAULT, 32627471, 'update_me', 4, DEFAULT, 0, 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 0, 0
```

Comment: I cannot generate a string in Access including just the word DEFAULT. Using Nz-function I can creat like that  Nz(arg, Default) but the string in the pt query "translate" it as 'Default', which leads to an error  "Error converting data type varchar to int". 

So the only way I found is to build the string with Nz(arg, 0) in Access and to Change the 0 value to Null in SQL as my fileds with datatype int have only values >0 ! As Long as I do not find a more elegant way it is the only solution that works.

Comment: @user3480989 - *"I cannot generate a string in Access including just the word DEFAULT."* - Of course you can. See the update to my answer.